# Java JIT compiler for download

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jit

I want to download a JIT compiler for Java. Where can I get a good JIT compiler?

Answer (score 6):

The JIT compiler runs as part as the JVM - it's not something you download and run separately.

In the early days of Java, you used to be able to run a JIT as a plugin - but these days there's no need. Any mainstream, modern desktop Java environment will include a JIT.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the JVMs have a JIT built in.  Download any of them.

My guess is you are looking for a java to native .exe compiler in the mistaken belief that this will yield a significant performance difference.  For Java this is not the case for most real applications and just makes deploying them harder.

Answer (score 1):

Any modern well-performing Java implementation comes with a JIT, and normally you do not have to worry about these kind of things.  The most frequent is the Oracle Java implementation available from http://java.com.

If you, however, have a performance problem it is usually a problem with your own code, so use a suitable profiler (jvisualvm in the Sun 6 JDK is a good, free starting point) to identify your bottlenecks, so you can correct them.